# X11 on cygwin - "Failed to activate core devices"

Tags: cygwin, x11

I try to start X11 on cygwin - "Failed to activate core devices"

XWin.0.log

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.15.0.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 erngab-PC 1.7.27(0.271/5/3) 2013-12-09 11:57 i686
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (WoW64)
Package: version 1.15.0-2 built 2014-01-11

XWin was started with the following command line:

xwin -nodecoration -rootless 

ddxProcessArgument - Initializing default screens
winInitializeScreenDefaults - primary monitor w 1920 h 1080
winInitializeScreenDefaults - native DPI x 96 y 96
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-Bigfont
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension Present
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  6236.888] Initializing built-in extension GLX
[  6236.888] (II) xorg.conf is not supported
[  6236.888] (II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
[  6236.888] LoadPreferences: Loading /cygdrive/d/home/.XWinrc
[  6237.075] winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw installed, allowing ShadowDD
[  6237.075] winDetectSupportedEngines - Windows NT, allowing PrimaryDD
[  6237.075] winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
[  6237.075] winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 0000001f
[  6237.075] winSetEngine - Using Shadow DirectDraw NonLocking
[  6237.075] winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
[  6237.294] winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
[  6237.309] MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
[  6237.309] XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
[  6237.325] (EE) AIGLX: No native OpenGL in modes with a root window
[  6237.528] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
[  6237.528] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  6237.528] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  6238.136] (EE) Couldn't open compiled keymap file /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
[  6238.136] (EE) XKB: Failed to load keymap. Loading default keymap instead.
[  6238.261] (EE) Couldn't open compiled keymap file /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
[  6238.261] XKB: Failed to compile keymap
[  6238.261] Keyboard initialization failed. This could be a missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config.
[  6238.261] (EE) Fatal server error: (EE) Failed to activate core devices.(EE) 
[  6238.261] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I was looking for a solution over the internet, not found anything - I do not know what the problem is (in fact I do not know for what to search).

any suggestions.
Regards!

Comment: This error means that XWin couldn't run xkbcomp successfully for some reason.  http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-failed-to-compile-keymap has some suggestions of possible causes.

Comment: In http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-failed-to-compile-keymap[link] write `Check that /usr/bin/xkbcomp can be run from a bash shell`. In /usr/bin/ i have xkbcomp.exe. When I tray `./xkbcomp.exe` appears `No input file specified`. How to `Check that /usr/bin/xkbcomp can be run from a bash shell`.

Comment: If it runs at all, that is a good enough check to start with.

Answer (score 0):

For me the suggestions outlined here: http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-failed-to-compile-keymap didn't work, but after I uninstalled a proxying program called "Hide My Ip" it worked.